# How to email a picture through a very restricted html page

Tags: html, ios, image, email, safari

I am attempting to setup a webpage connected to my companies internal Intranet page that will be restricted to simply allow an iPad to take a picture, then email the picture through our web mail app. The html code I have so far just lets me take a picture, or select a picture from the local library. If you leave the page and come back the picture is gone and you can't save any of the pictures you took through the webpage. I need to be able to email those through the web mail app. Any assistance would be very appreciated. The browser is safari.
HTML Below:

```
input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField">
    <img id="yourimage">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to use cookies or indexedDb to save temporary files, at least till you made a choice if you want to upload the photo or not, then you can send the photo to the desired email using PHP

Comment: There will be different people using different email addresses so I can't set one specific address.. do you know any PHP that creates an option to basically save the file as an attachment and reroute you to the mail app and let you login then email..? I know this is much more complicated than it sounds but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @Jaydon check on new answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here it's! Do **NOT** forget you should create the folder with the name `uploads` on the folder where you have to put these files!

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your email
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br/>
    Select image to upload:<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
  {
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $file_name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files (filename,email) 
            VALUES ('$file_name','$email')");
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

  }


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

database.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `files`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `files`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```